# All texts in the app are gone after a while

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is probably the weirdest thing it ever happened to me. I inherit this code from another developer and I can't figure out which is the problem.

The app uses the sherlocknabvar and it also has a screen with a mapfragment where you can move a pin around and once the map is settled it calls several APIs to get some info about your position. The rest of the activities are pretty normal, nothing fancy about them. The map activity is quite complex though.

This is the error I have... weirdest thing is that it only happens sometimes, so it's not easy to reproduce it but I still can see it happen from time to time.

After playing with the map for a while (moving the pin, zooming in and out and so on) if I go back to the main activity (by clicking a home button on the navbar or by clicking the back button) all the texts in my app are gone in all the activities. I can see all the different layouts with images and colours but all the texts are completely gone. The only way to have them back is by restarting the app.

Looking at the Android Device Monitor (in case was some memory leak) everything looked pretty stable (28016K/33287K as max) and even worst, I can reproduce that error in an old Sony Xperia but also in a new brand S5.

**EDIT**

I found out that the texts where not missing, the color was changing to transparent for some reason that I still don't get. I disabled the hardware acceleration and it works but I'm still wondering what the problem could be and why that changed fixed it.

This is one of the layouts I'm having problems with, all the TextViews just change to transparent without any reason. It happens to the TextViews that have an 'static' text and also to the ones that I change the text dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/new_bg_background_app"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anc_button"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anc_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lb_confirmed"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Font50PX"                
             />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ic_confirmed"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/new_ic_active"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anc_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_pick_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ic_confirmed"
        android:text="@string/lb_your_pick_up"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font28PX"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_passengers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lb_pick_up"
        android:text="5 Passengers"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font50PX"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_passengers"
        android:text="@string/lb_from"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font28PX"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lb_from"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font50PX"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_post_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_address"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font45PX"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_at"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_post_code"
        android:text="@string/lb_at"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font28PX"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lb_at"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font50PX"
        android:text="9:00 AM Today"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/lb_mini"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Font26PX"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_note"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lb_reference"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lb_reference"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Font32PX"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_reference"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lb_reference"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Font28PX"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/anc_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/lb_done"
        android:background="@drawable/new_btn_orange"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:onClick="onDone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Think you might need to post some code in order for any one to have any help to provide you a suggestion

Comment: Problem is that I don't know which part of the code it's actually related to the problem, that's why I asked more a generic question. I've been doing some testing and I updated the question with some code but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: If this activity is using a Dialog Theme, which it sounds like it is, there's no need to do ``requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`` as this is already done. Might be worthwhile removing this and re-testing

Comment: After trying a lot of different stuff, I ended up deleting pretty much all the code to reduce the problem and I still had the same issue. 

I found out that the texts were not missing, but there were all transparent (weird). At the end I disabled the hardware acceleration and it works now. But I'm still wondering what could be the problem.

Comment: Can you post the layout file for the textviews you are experiencing the problem with

Comment: I'm experiencing the problem in all the layouts. I just posted on of them, they are all quite similar. I've also realised that if you keep using the app for a while, some of texts go back to its original color. It's just really odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed after disabling the hardware acceleration in the manifest just for the activity I was having the problem with

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```